# Please help me understand the editor comments regarding reference format in the manuscript

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

A paper of mine has been accepted today for publication in Physical Review E. :) But, the editor wants me to change the reference format. His comment is:

"* The format of the references in your manuscript does not conform to our style, as can be seen in any recently published paper. Our general style  (titles encouraged) is: [23] Y. Tserkovnyak, A. Brataas, and G. E. W. Bauer, Enhanced Gilbert Damping in Thin   Ferromagnetic Films, Phys. Rev. Lett. 88, 117601 (2002)."

A screenshot of my current reference format in the manuscript is shown here.
[image]

So, what is that the editor is suggesting? Is it to put the year in round brackets, like (2009)?

Comment: Which bibliographystyle do you use? For Physical Review you could try `apsrev4-2.bst`.

Comment: This is what I have in my tex file. \bibliographystyle{unsrt}

Comment: @Marjin, how do I achieve that?

Comment: My document class is this, \documentclass[%preprint,singleocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,aps,pre,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

Comment: FIXED IT. Thanks Marjin! Just this was needed. \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1.bst}